# get value from dropdown. (little tricky)

Tags: php, javascript, html, get

First of all, im quite new to PHP and coding, but here goes.

I have a web form, that has to get some info from a txt file (located in a folder on the server)
I got how to make it get the info from the file and how to make the dropdown list, show all files in the folder.
How ever what i cant figure out is how to make them work together, so the file name it reads from, is taken from the selected value of the dropdown list.

the code for the dropdown list:

```
<? 
$currentdir = 'files'; //change to your directory 
$dir = opendir($currentdir); 

echo 'Files are as follows:<br>'; 
echo '<select name="select">'; 
while($file = readdir($dir)) 
{ 
    echo '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>'; 
} 
echo '</select>'; 
closedir($dir); ?>
```

and the code to read from the file:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php $myFile = ""; $lines = file($myFile); echo $lines[2]; ?>" name="refnr" id="refnr" class="input" />
```

lets say the drop down shows 2 files,  test.txt and test2.txt,  if i select test2.txt from the dropdown, i wanted it to put "test2.txt" in between the "" at `<?php $myFile = ""`;
but no matter how i try to put the code in there to get the selected value, it just fails...

The full code of my Form as it is right now:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    // Used for later to determine result
    $success = $error = false;

    // Object syntax looks better and is easier to use than arrays to me
    $post = new stdClass;

    // Usually there would be much more validation and filtering, but this
    // will work for now.
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
        $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));

    // Check for blank fields
    if (empty($post->refnr))
        $error = true;

    else {

        // Get this directory, to include other files from
        $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

        // Get the contents of the pdf into a variable for later
        ob_start();
        require_once($dir.'/pdf.php');
        $pdf_html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // Load the dompdf files
        require_once($dir.'/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // Create new instance of dompdf
        $dompdf->load_html($pdf_html); // Load the html
        $dompdf->render(); // Parse the html, convert to PDF
        $pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); // Put contents of pdf into variable for later

        // Get the contents of the HTML email into a variable for later
        ob_start();
        require_once($dir.'/html.php');
        $html_message = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // Load the SwiftMailer files
        require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');

        $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport()); // Create new instance of SwiftMailer

        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                       ->setSubject('Felanmalan') // Message subject
                       ->setTo(array('mymail@hidden' => 'Fel')) // Array of people to send to
                       ->setFrom(array('mymail@hidden' => 'Fel')) // From:
                       ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') // Attach that HTML message from earlier
                       ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content, 'Felanmalan.pdf', 'application/pdf')); // Attach the generated PDF from earlier

        // Send the email, and show user message
        if ($mailer->send($message))
            $success = true;
        else
            $error = true;

    }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Felanm&auml;lan fr&aring;n IKEA</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, span, ul, li, div, form, input, select, textarea, button {margin:0; padding:0;}
        ul {list-style:none;}
        a, a:hover {text-decoration:none; outline:0;}
        a img {border:0;}

        body {font:12px/16px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; background:#ffffff;}
        #container {width:450px; margin:10px auto; padding:10px; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; background:#F9F9F9;}
        #container h1 {margin-bottom:20px; font-size:40px; line-height:40px; font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:normal;}
        .message {margin-bottom:10px; padding:5px;}
        .success {color:#4F8A10; border:1px solid #4F8A10; background:#DFF2BF;}
        .error {color:#D8000C; border:1px solid #D8000C; background:#FFBABA;}
        label {display:block; margin-bottom:3px; cursor:pointer;}
        .input, textarea, select, button {display:block; width:440px; margin-bottom:10px; padding:3px; font:22px/22px 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border:1px solid #CCC; border-top-width:2px;}
        textarea {font-size:13px; line-height:16px;}
        select {width:396px;}
        button {float:right; width:auto; margin-bottom:0; padding:3px 30px; cursor:pointer; font-size:16px; border:1px solid #999; border-bottom-width:2px; border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; background:#EEE;}
        button:active {border-bottom-width:1px; padding:4px 30px 3px; background:#E9E9E9;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<? 
$currentdir = 'files'; //change to your directory 
$dir = opendir($currentdir); 

echo 'Files are as follows:<br>'; 
echo '<select name="select">'; 
while($file = readdir($dir)) 
{ 
    echo '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>'; 
} 
echo '</select>'; 
closedir($dir); ?>

    <div id="container">

        <h1><img src="felimg.png" />  Felanm&auml;lan</h1>

        <?php if ($success) { ?>
            <div class="message success">
                <h4>Congratulations! It worked! Now check your email.</h4>
            </div>
        <?php } elseif ($error) { ?>
            <div class="message error">
                <h4>Sorry, an error occurred. Try again!</h4>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <label for="date"><b>Date:</b></label>
            <input type="text" readonly name="date" id="date" class="input" value="<? print(Date("Y-m-d")); ?>"/>

            <label for="refnr"><b>Referensnummer:</b></label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php $myFile = ""; $lines = file($myFile); echo $lines[2]; ?>" name="refnr" id="refnr" class="input" />

            <label for="bestav"><b>Best&auml;lld av:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="bestav" id="bestav" class="input" />           

            <label for="tel"><b>Tel:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" class="input" />

            <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input" />         

            <label for="kund"><b>Kund:</b></label>
            <textarea name="kund" id="kund" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>

            <label for="ktel"><b>Tel:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="ktel" id="ktel" class="input" />

            <label for="art"><b>Ber&ouml;rd Artikel:</b></label>
            <textarea name="art" id="art" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>

            <label for="fel"><b>Fel p&aring; varan: </b></label>
            <textarea name="fel" id="fel" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>

            <label for="q1"><b>Installation gjord av fackman:</b></label>
            <select name="q1" id="q1">
                <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
                <option value="Nej">Nej</option>
            </select>

            <label for="q2"><b>Serviceverkstad:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="q2" id="q2" class="input" />

            <label for="q3"><b>Servicenr:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="q3" id="q3" class="input" />

            <label for="q4"><b>Serienr:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="q4" id="q4" class="input" />

            <label for="q5"><b>Inom garanti eller reklamation:</b></label>
            <select name="q5" id="q5">
                <option value="Garanti">Garanti</option>
                <option value="Reklamation">Reklamation</option>
            </select>

            <label for="q6"><b>Informerat om punkt 8:</b></label>
            <select name="q6" id="q6">
                <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
                <option value="Nej">Nej</option>
            </select>           

            <label for="q7"><b>Har kund sj&auml;lv g&aring;tt igenom manual f&ouml;r fels&ouml;kning:</b></label>
            <select name="q7" id="q7">
                <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
                <option value="Nej">Nej</option>
            </select>               

            <label for="q8"><b>Ordernr:</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="q8" id="q8" class="input" />

            <label for="q9"><b>Ink&ouml;psdatum:</b></label>
            <input type="date" name="q9" id="q9" class="input" /><br>


            <p><button type="submit">Submit!</button></p>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

hope it makes sense and again, sorry if it turns out to be a noob question :) i have used 2 days googling and testing and i have simply come to a point where i need a little push in the right direction again.

Thanks in advance.

p.s to explain short what my goal is, then i have 1 webform that generates a txt file and saves it on a server, then another form, where the "admin" can choose the file from the drop down, get the info in that the client filled out in the txt version and then fill out what he needs to fill out and then have it saved and sent as a PDF to a technician.

Comment: Though not mandatory, using a database may be easier, instead of dealing with text files.

Comment: replacing `<?` with `<?php` may solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
echo '<select id="select" name="select">'; 
while($file = readdir($dir)) 
{ 
    echo '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>'; 
} 
echo '</select>';
```

And after it has been loaded to the DOM, use

```
document.getElementById('select').onchange=changeSelect;
function changeSelect(){
    document.getElementById('refnr').value=document.getElementById('select').value;
}
changeSelect();
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7nzBS/

Answer (score 0):

```
I wanted it to put "test2.txt" in between the "" at `<?php $myFile = ""`
```

You can't do such a thing, because the `"text2.txt"` is at the client side and the `$myfile`, php variable, is at the server side. If you want to access data of a client side from server side, you need to send data via HTTP. So you have two choices:

1. Send the selected value via HTTP **post** or **get**.
2. Send the selected value via **AJAX**.

Comment: I'm sorry i might have explained it a bit unclear.  
The test2.txt is also located on the server, all files are.

When the Client fills in the date, in the web form it generates a .txt file with the info in.  That file is being placed in a folder on the server.
Then the Admin ( supporter ) can see the .txt files from the drop down menu, from their web form and from there, fill in the remaining info needed and then they generate a PDF document out of it, that will be sent to the Technician.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Oriol, that worked :)

the code now looks like this and is working as i needed it to.
Also thanks for all other suggestions, lovely with quick and helpful replies :)

```
            <label for="refnr"><b>Referensnummer:</b></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php $selectedfile = @$_POST['file2']; $myFile = "files/$selectedfile"; $lines = file($myFile); echo $lines[0]; ?>" name="refnr" id="refnr" class="input" />
```